# How to get the address of an object in an NSMutableArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, pointers

How can I get the Address of an object stored in a NSMutableArray?

I have something like this:

class member variable in .h:

```
MyClass *__strong*_selectedobject;
```

in a function in .m:

```
MyClass *objReference = [_messageBoards objectAtIndex:idxInCaseOfContract];
_selectedobject = &objReference;
```

the problem is, that `_selectedobject`is `nil` as soon as the function finishes.

`_selectedobject` is an instance variable within a singleton class. It works with other objects which are not within an array. Also, the object within the array is not suddenly nil, it is just the reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATE

I'm just posting here how you can store reference to address in object(as question was originally about that), however I strongly advice anyone to think again if this is actually needed:

```
@interface MyClass : NSObject
{   
    NSMutableArray* test;
    __strong id* foo;
}

    *foo = [test objectAtIndex:2];
```

ORIGINAL ANSWER

As @Vijay-Apple-Dev.blogspot pointed out you are missing something very important about memory - you are making _selectedobject to point to address of temporary variable(objReference) instead of object in memory([_messageBoards objectAtIndex:idxInCaseOfContract]). All method variables becomes nil after their method goes out of scope, and thats why your reference becomes nil(although array is still alive and object is there). Simply do not use local variable and everything should be fine.

Side note - what's the purpose of using address reference instead of object pointer? If you think you're gone save memory you are wrong, as ARC(and MRC also) are working differently ;)

Comment: I cannot do it directly, ´_selectedobject = &[_messageBoards objectAtIndex:idxInCaseOfContract];` throws an error

Comment: But you were right, I was overthinking it, saving a object pointer is enough

Answer (score 2):

You can not get pointer to a position inside an array in Objective-C.

If you need to retain position in an array, so that if another object is written there you'll have it instead of the old one, then save index of that position (and retain the array too if needed). Mind that modifications to the array may render the index invalid.

If you need to retain only the object which was read from array at that moment, simply retain that object. Object address is the object pointer itself, there are no extra indirections.

Comment: You are right, if a adress of an object is needed a C style array should be used, the address of an object in an NSMutableArray may change

Answer (score 0):

MyClass *objReference is local variable to the method. So once it method finishes, everything will be gone from memory. If you want to keep them, then you have retain them in header file(.h) as instance variable.

```
  @property(nonatomic,retain) MyClass *objReference;
```

then

```
  self.objReference = [_messageBoards objectAtIndex:idxInCaseOfContract];
```

**NOTE: You must use the self dot syntax when u retain the object. otherwise wont work.**

Comment: It is already an instance variable, see the comments. The code is just 2 snippets from the whole class.